# incorrect openssl output in cmd (doesn't write to file)

Tags: openssl, cmd, output

My purpose is verifying cms message, my choice for instrument is openssl application. Operation is `openssl smime -verify -in [fileName] -inform der -noverify -out [outputFileName]` (argument `-noverify` is caused the problem with root certificate, i think it is not matter, this problem will be solved after)). 
The result in window of cmd console is "Verify successfull" (digital signature is true without check with high-level certificate). 
But the info in output file is in incorrect encoding i think (i check for all c# encoding trying to read this file, but it is something another). If i run operation in powershell and logging working in console, history not include output of ONLY openssl operation. 
I wrote small app on c# for output of process in messagebox and the data of messagebox is empty.
So i really need your advice how to solve my task.